# How to merge tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, union

I want to merge two tables from different schemas in the same PostgreSQL database but I could not get a query to work.

The two tables have lots of columns and samples, I want to select A and B from table 1, and I want to select C, D, E from table 2, where B and C items are exactly the same thing but numbers contained are not totally the same. Thus I want to merge and get A (B/C) D E.

I tried to use `UNION` but I got an error:

```
[42601]: ERROR: each UNION query must have the same number of columns.
```

And when I used `LEFT JOIN` it shows mistake around `'.'`.
In the last try my code looked like:

```
select A from table1 left join
table2.D, table2.E using B=C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of query:

**Table**

```
create table table1 (
    A text,
    B int
);
insert into table1 values ('test-a', 123);

create table table2 (
    C int,
    D text,
    E text
);
insert into table2 values (3456, 'test-d', 'test-e');
```

**Query**

```
select A::text, B::text as BC, '' as D, '' as E from table1
union all
select '' as A, C::text as BC, D::text, E::text from table2
```

**Result**

```
a       bc   d      e
test-a  123     
3456         test-d test-e
```

That'll take all records from table1 (columns A, B, dummy column D and dummy column E) and add to it records from table2 (dummy column A, column C, D and E)

Example: https://rextester.com/NWSEP53051

## If you are using SQLite

**Tables**

```
create table table1 (A, B);
insert into table1 values ('test-a', 123);

create table table2 (C, D, E);
insert into table2 values (3456, 'test-d', 'test-e');
```

**Query**

```
select A, B as BC, '' as D, '' as E from table1
union all
select '' as A, C as BC, D, E from table2
```

**Result**

```
| A      | BC   | D      | E      |
| ------ | ---- | ------ | ------ |
| test-a | 123  |        |        |
|        | 3456 | test-d | test-e |
```

Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rE1MeJQpjGH4FZVwWmTpEX/0

Comment: Thanks for your help so much! But one question is , when I just copy your code, it works well if I delete ::text (maybe caused by DBeaver?), but when I changed it into my case, it shows: SQL  [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "union". Do you mind giving me some tips on improving it?
  Position: 1

Comment: Why are you deleting `::text`? The `::text` means convert whatever is in that column to text data. If you have mismatching data types between each parallel column from both tables, PostgreSQL will give you the error you are seeing. If you need further help, you will have tell me the datatype of each of the columns of both tables.

Comment: Because it notices me  [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (unrecognized token: ":"). And in my original data, it is all text type. Thx!

Comment: Are you using SQLite or PostgreSQL?

Comment: I've added an example of SQLite as well in case that's what you are using.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement merge using a temporary table

1. lock table test_tbl in exclusive mode;
2. data delete
3. update
4. insert

https://parksuseong.blogspot.com/2019/07/postgresql-insert-merge-olap.html